# Apache forces Cache-Control: private automatically for HTTPS requests

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, cache, rhel6

I'm trying to get browsers to cache assets over **HTTPS**. I am using *MD5 fingerprinting* method to allow long-term caching and I have this part working OK.

What doesn't work is setting the **Cache-Control** headers in Apache.

My config for both *regular* and *SSL* vhost contains:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 year"
```

**HTTP** request to */test.css* produces headers:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Content-Type: text/css
Date: Wed, 15 May 2013 10:33:01 GMT
Etag: "7e572-19-4dcbdc8c04529"
Expires: Thu, 15 May 2014 10:33:01 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 May 2013 08:46:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Oracle)
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

But **HTTPS** request to same file produces headers:

```
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
Content-Type: text/css
Date: Wed, 15 May 2013 10:33:58 GMT
Etag: "7e572-19-4dcbdc8c04529"
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 May 2013 08:46:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Oracle)
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

BTW, Adding this right after the *ExpiresByType*:

```
Header unset Expires
Header unset Cache-Control
```

removes these headers from HTTP, but *not* from HTTPS request.

Also, I have verified that any other header I set gets passed, but not cache related headers like *Cache-Control* or *Expires* - these get overwritten somewhere.

Is this normal Apache behavior or some Oracle or Red Hat patch that aims to security?

Can this be turned off somehow?

**System info:**

```
OS: Oracle Linux 6.4 (RHEL 6.4 based)
Apache: 2.2.15 (from rpm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Cache control: public directive` to enable **HTTPS caching for Firefox**.

Some versions of Firefox require that the `Cache control: public` header to be set in order for resources sent over SSL to be cached on disk, even if the other caching headers are explicitly set. Although this header is normally used to enable caching by proxy servers (as described below), proxies cannot cache any content sent over HTTPS, so **it is always safe to set this header for HTTPS resources**

Source: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching

Comment: If you reread the question - it is exactly about how to do this in RHEL Apache as it seems to overwrite whatever I put into `Cache-Control` header.